# How to disable a list of checkboxes (ListBoxFor) using a second (single) checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a listbox with a bunch of race/ethnicity options in it that need to be disabled when you click a specific option (in this case, not reported).  I have code to replace the existing list of checkboxes with a single option if Not Reported is chosen (since you shouldn't be able to select "not reported" and "asian" for instance), but I need to either uncheck or disable the other list when you select the new checkbox that appears.

Here's an example of the HTML:

```
    <div class="field inline spacer20 hideIfRaceEthnicityIsNo showIfRaceEthnicityIsYes" style="display: none" id="RaceListDiv">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubjectRaceAndEthnicity.Race, new { @class = "colon", @required = "required" })
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedRaceItems, Model.RaceEnumList, new { id = "RaceDiv" })
    </div>
    <div class="field inline spacer20 hideIfRaceEthnicityIsNo" style="display: none" id="NotReportedDiv">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubjectRaceAndEthnicity.Race, new { @class = "colon", @required = "required" })
        @Html.IXRS_CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsNotReportedOnly, CustomWebPrompt.NotReported@*, new { id = "NotReportedCheckbox" }*@)
    </div>
```

And here's the jquery as it currently stands (I still need to add the uncheck logic).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.multiselect .multi').on("change", function () {

        var raceMultiSelect = $(this).children('a');
        var raceMultiValue = raceMultiSelect.attr('id');
        var raceMultiChecked = raceMultiSelect.hasClass('checked');

        var AsianSubselectDiv = $('#AsianSubselectDiv');
        var APACSubselectDiv = $('#APACSubselectDiv');

        var RaceListDiv = $('#RaceListDiv');
        var NotReportedDiv = $('#NotReportedDiv');
        var UnknownDiv = $('#UnknownDiv');

        if (raceMultiValue === "Not_reported") {
            if (raceMultiChecked) {
                RaceListDiv.hide();
                NotReportedDiv.show();
            }
        }
        $("#NotReportedDiv input:checkbox").change(function () {
            var ischecked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if (ischecked) {
            //uncheck logic goes here
            }
            if (!ischecked) {
                RaceListDiv.show();
                NotReportedDiv.hide();
            }
        });

        if (raceMultiValue === "Unknown") {
            if (raceMultiChecked) {
                RaceListDiv.hide();
                UnknownDiv.show();
            }
        }
        $("#UnknownDiv input:checkbox").change(function () {
            var ischecked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if (ischecked) {
            //uncheck logic goes here
            }
            if (!ischecked) {
                RaceListDiv.show();
                UnknownDiv.hide();
            }
        });

        if (raceMultiValue === 'Asian_(Select_all_that_apply)') {
            if (raceMultiChecked) {
                AsianSubselectDiv.show();
            } else {
                AsianSubselectDiv.hide();
            }
        }
        if (raceMultiValue === 'Native_Hawaiian_OR_Other_Pacific_Islander_(Select_all_that_apply)') {
            if (raceMultiChecked) {
                APACSubselectDiv.show();
            } else {
                APACSubselectDiv.hide();
            }      
        }
    });
});
```

I've been searching the forums and I've found a few posts that are similar, but nothing that is exactly what I'm looking for (or that works).

A few commands I've tried:

```
$(function () {
                    $("#NotReportedDiv").change(function () {
                        $("#RaceDiv").find("option").prop("selected", this.checked)

                    });
                });

                $("#RaceDiv").find("option").prop("selected", this.checked);
                $('#RaceDiv').prop("disabled", $(this).prop('checked'));

                RaceListDiv.removeProp(':checked');

                RaceListDiv.child.prop('checked', false);
                RaceListDiv.parent.prop('checked', false);

                $('#RaceListDiv input:checkbox').is(":checked").prop('checked', false);

                RaceListDiv.children.prop('checked', false);
```

Honestly I feel like I've gotten close a few times, but jQuery is new to me and I've only learned it in the last 6 months or so... and I've asked around and even guys at work who know this stuff have been stumped... any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - this is not a C# question so please get rid of all C# and post only RENDERED relevant HTML and relevant JS